# I am getting TimeOutException in Infinispan Cache

Tags: java, infinispan

Below is my configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:4.2 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-4.2.xsd"
      xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:4.2">

   <global>
      <transport clusterName="DEV2" transportClass="org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport">
   <properties>
    <property name="configurationFile" value="../jgroups-tcp.xml" />
   </properties>
  </transport>
   </global>

   <default>
      <clustering mode="distribution">
         <l1 enabled="false"/>
         <hash numOwners="1" rehashRpcTimeout="120000"/>
         <sync/>  
      </clustering>
  <eviction strategy="FIFO" maxEntries="1"/>
  <expiration lifespan="1000" maxIdle="500" />
   </default>
</infinispan>
```

Below is my exception trace out:

```
Caused by: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Unable to acquire lock after [10 seconds] on key [178328] for requestor [Thread[http-10.226.32.128-5000-Processor10,5,main]]! Lock held by [(another thread)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I configured the locking property useLockStriping = "false". This will create a lock for the each entry added to the cache. This solves my issue